# Search for version range in Shodan

Tags: shodan

I am trying to do a version range search within **Shodan** as a one-liner but having trouble doing so.
Not eve sure if that is possible, but basically, I am able to get search results if I did it 2 times as follows:

```
software 1.5.*
software 1.6.*
```

Is it possible to combine the above two lines into one, so that it will lists me all the 1.5.* and 1.6.* results all at one go?

Adding on, I wasn't able to find much info on the search syntax online..
Tried writing like `software 1.[5|6].*` but it returns me invalid result.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the **version** filter and provide it with a comma-separated list of values. For example, the following would find Microsoft IIS servers that are either 5.0 OR 6.0:

```
product:microsoft-iis version:5.0,6.0
```

The basic rules of the Shodan search syntax are outlined in this article:

https://help.shodan.io/the-basics/search-query-fundamentals

Values provided in filters are OR-ed together and everything else is AND-ed together. Shodan search syntax doesn't support wildcards currently. If the property you're searching for is always numeric then you can also search for ranges:

```
port:<1024
```

This blog post covers it in further detail:

https://blog.shodan.io/search-engine-improvements/

And the list of available search filters is here:

https://beta.shodan.io/search/filters

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. So.. it turns out I am wrong, apparently the software "version range" I am looking for is actually under the product name (eg. `software-1.5.16`) instead, as it does not have a `version` field. Tried using your method and it does not works though, any insight?